# Input ZIP code to html form in Android WebView

Tags: javascript, android, html, webview

I use loadurl() downloading http://ziplookup.googlecode.com/git/index.html to my WebView, and try to input ZipCode from JavaScript code.

```
String cmd = "document.getElementsByClassName('zip-lookup-field-zipcod')[0].value='10303';";
webview.evaluateJavascript(cmd, view-call-back);
```

The zipcode is input but city and state are not triggered to be filled. How can I do it programmatically? No problem if I input zip code manually.